# I want to make Full text search with multiple words for multiple columns

Tags: php, full-text-search, multiple-columns

I want to make a full text search with multiple words for multiple columns.

I.e.: I want to search  for 'doctor' located in London.

This is the statement I am using, but it doesn't work well:

```
select * from mytable  where  MATCH (job,address)   
  AGAINST ('+doctor +london' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: What about this doesn't work exactly? Can you add more detail in your question about where you are getting stuck?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for an SQL statement to search in a database? Please be more specific on the data source.

Comment: I'm using mysql , with IN BOOLEAN MODE will search for london in the address but without  IN BOOLEAN MODE will search for london in address , but I want to search with doctor in job and london in address